# AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name... for every resource mentioned AppManifest.xml

Tags: android, c++, google-people-api

I have an older app that I need to refresh in order to update it for the Google Play Store. It's a native C++ app. The code and set-up are extremely brittle any time I am forced to update to a new toolset/API version. I am able to compile and link the so on the native side, however, AAPT seems to die on me with the following output:

```
1>  Custom package for R class: 'com.pcct.proj21'
1>  Starting process 'command 'C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe''. Working directory: D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android Command: C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar -M \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\generated\source\r\release -F D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\res\resources-release.ap_ --custom-package com.pcct.proj21 -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors
1>  Successfully started process 'command 'C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe''
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:69:25-44: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'banner' with value '@drawable/bannerWTF').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:70:23-42: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:72:24-40: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:77:28-44: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:84:28-44: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:108:28-44: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'banner' with value '@drawable/banner').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:73: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
1>
1>  \\?\D:\Storage\PROJ_21\PROJ_21\Android\PROJ_21_Android\Tegra-Android\Release\PROJ_21_Android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:104: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
```

The locations of these resources seem correct:

- The strings are in res/values/strings.xml and they exist.
- The images that AAPT is having trouble dealing with are also in their correct spot(s) in drawable and mipmap (mipmap having a number of DPI-specific folders, etc).

These resources missing are all of the resources in the AppManifest.xml.  Here is the contents of the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.pcct.proj21" 
    android:versionCode="1000010" 
    android:versionName="1.0.10" 
    android:installLocation="auto" 
    android:sharedUserId="com.pcct.proj21">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
               android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
               android:allowBackup="true" 
               android:banner="@drawable/banner" 
               android:isGame="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" 
              android:launchMode="singleTask" 
              android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection" 
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" 
              android:launchMode="singleTask" 
              android:name=".DownloaderActivity" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="tv.ouya.intent.category.GAME" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
    <activity android:name=".RestartMainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified" android:process=":RestartMainActivity"/>
    <service android:name=".DummyService" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection" android:enabled="true"/>
    <service android:name=".DownloaderService"/>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
  </application>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gamepad" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor" android:required="false"/>

</manifest>
```

I'm using gradle to build this but the issue seems to stem from AAPT.
The APK resources look good. The dexdump and aapt header listing all show that these values look good (I compared against other app that work).

This feels like something "very easy" but I am clearly not seeing it.

In the source to AAPT I see that this function has a static at the top of the source to give more detailed output.

```
uint32_t ResourceTable::getResId(const String16& ref,
                                 const String16* defType,
                                 const String16* defPackage,
                                 const char** outErrorMsg,
                                 bool onlyPublic) const
{
    String16 package, type, name;
    bool refOnlyPublic = true;
    if (!ResTable::expandResourceRef(
        ref.string(), ref.size(), &package, &type, &name,
        defType, defPackage ? defPackage:&mAssetsPackage,
        outErrorMsg, &refOnlyPublic)) {
        if (kIsDebug) {
            printf("Expanding resource: ref=%s\n", String8(ref).string());
            printf("Expanding resource: defType=%s\n",
                    defType ? String8(*defType).string() : "NULL");
            printf("Expanding resource: defPackage=%s\n",
                    defPackage ? String8(*defPackage).string() : "NULL");
            printf("Expanding resource: ref=%s\n", String8(ref).string());
            printf("Expanded resource: p=%s, t=%s, n=%s, res=0\n",
                    String8(package).string(), String8(type).string(),
                    String8(name).string());
        }
        return 0;
    }
    uint32_t res = getResId(package, type, name, onlyPublic && refOnlyPublic);
    if (kIsDebug) {
        printf("Expanded resource: p=%s, t=%s, n=%s, res=%d\n",
                String8(package).string(), String8(type).string(),
                String8(name).string(), res);
    }
    if (res == 0) {
        if (outErrorMsg)
            *outErrorMsg = "No resource found that matches the given name";
    }
    return res;
}
```

Is there a way to quickly get a version of this with that set for Windows without going through all of the pain of getting it to compile?

Comment: Hey guys, any suggestions for this?

Is there a build of AAPT that has the debugging output for the function ResourceTable::getResId() (the variable kIsDebug set to true)?

Comment: Is there any way to ping the team that can give support on this issue? Formatting the question is great, but can someone take a stab at an answer?